# Typeahead.js jsonp callback

Tags: callback, jsonp, typeahead.js

Typeahead.js supports JSONP. I'm successfully sending and receiving JSONP data, I can see it in the console. However, the results aren't showing up in Typeahead.

PHP Server is sending

```
echo "callback".'('.json_encode($aout).');';
```

Which looks like

```
callback(["A 00000091","A 00000091s CHI","A 00000091s HENN","A 00086479","A 00086479sss","A 00144927sss%HEN","A 00165660s HEN","A 00324221sss","A 00325126 CsSP","A 00344270sss",""]);
```

My call back function

```
<script>
window.callback = function(data){
    console.log(data);
};
</script>
```

Typeahead init

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".myTypeHead").typeahead({
    name: "search",
    remote : {
        url : "http://zonessocialmedia.com/~zones/testing/search/search.php?search=%QUERY&callback=callback",
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    }
}); 
});
```

I'm able to see the data in the log, how can I add it to Typeahead? I'm using JSONP because of cross domain issues.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what the symptom here is. You should do `return data` within `window.callback` and it should simply work.

Comment: I've added return data to my window.callback and I see no change. http://zonessocialmedia.com/~zones/testing/search/test.html